# Can I unlock my Razr M (Verizon) for international use?

Tags: sim-unlocking, verizon

I have a Verizon Razr M that was given to me for free. It's a Verizon model, but it has never seen a network. (I use it as an  WiFI android iPod touch for now)

I know about CDMA/GSM/4G and all that. But doesn't it have a 3G radio for roaming? I don't need it to ever hit 4G/LTE/CDMA, but it would be nice to have it see 3G networks for me to drop a cheapo SIM into when I go out. Is this possible, or is this hardwired into the baseband with no hope for me. Are there unlock codes for this? I'm new to rooting android,, but a root doesn't seem to help unless I can reflash the baseband.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it's a single byte on the phone that determines whether the phone is GSM locked or not. Someone found this, and made a [nice tutorial on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2166542) on how to flip this byte.

The instructions look scarier than they really are. The detail is not because it's complicated, but because they show every single step.

The hard part for me was prepping my Windows box to be able to do this; you need Motorola Drivers and the .NET run-time for the Motorola diagnostic/programming application.

Answer (score 2):

All Motorola phones are unlocked for use overseas.  These phones will not work for AT&T and T-Mobile, but they do work out of the USA(I have used one myself)